# Create a list of unique keys in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of

```
[{"1":"value"},{"1":"second_value"},{"2":"third_value"},{"2":"fourth_value"},{"3":"fifth_value"}]
```

want to convert it into

```
[{"1":"value","2":"third_value","3":"fifth_value"},{"1":"second_value","2":"fourth_value"}]
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @SimeonVisser am making a new list checking that it contain the key or not

Comment: Is it limited to just "values", and "second_values"?

Comment: @Jordonias it can n no of values but I have to make a dict of each unique set of key in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a cleaner way of doing this, input is appreciated:

```
d = [{"1":"value"},{"1":"second_value"},{"2":"third_value"},{"2":"fourth_value"},{"3":"fifth_value"}]

results = [{}]
for item in stuff:
    j,k = item.items()[0]  // Do the initial dicts always contain one key-value pair?
    for result in results:
        if j not in result:
            result[j] = k
            break
        if result == results[-1]:
            results.append(item)
            break
```

Result:

```
[{'1': 'value', '3': 'fifth_value', '2': 'third_value'}, {'1': 'second_value', '2': 'fourth_value'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> result = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in d:
...     result[item.values()[0]].append(item.keys()[0])
...
>>> [{key: value for key in keys} for value, keys in result.items()]
[{'1': 'second_value', '2': 'second_value'}, {'1': 'value', '3': 'value', '2': 'value'}]
```

Note that `second_value` comes before `value` in this as the ordering is rather arbitrary (unless you were to explicitly specify that `value` should be ordered before `second_value` the above would give you the ordering that the dictionary returns).

Comment: Suppose list contain all distinct values

Comment: @Arpit great, you changed the meaning of the question to something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` here. Iterate over the list, use the values as keys and collect all the keys related to a value in a list.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)                                                            
for dic in lis:
    for k, v in dic.items():
        d[v].append(k)
...
```

Now `d` becomes:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
{'second_value': ['1', '2'],
 'value': ['1', '2', '3']})
```

Now iterate over `d` to get the desired result:

```
>>> [{v1:k for v1 in v} for k, v in d.items()]
[{'1': 'second_value', '2': 'second_value'}, {'1': 'value', '3': 'value', '2': 'value'}]
```

Comment: Suppose list contain all distinct values

Comment: @Arpit Post an example in question body.